# FireFox 43 is working intermittently with Selenium 2.48 Java Code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using firefox 43, selenium 2.48. Sometimes, the code gets executed end to end but sometimes, it doesn't work at the very first step itself such login, clicking etc.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code trials, error messages etc.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 2.48 support until Firefox 41, and Selenium 2.48 has an know [issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1202) on click.  Try Selenium [2.51.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG) or later.

Comment: yeah, I have tried 2.53 now, It's working at least for now. Thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's you wanted, thus the question status is not unresolved. And others can know which is correct answer to fix the issue.